# docker-compose oci runtime error starting container process caused connection reset by peer

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I updated docker and compose to

```
Docker version 17.06.0-ce, build 02c1d87

docker-compose version 1.14.0, build c7bdf9e
```

Now when I am running container with docker run it works fine. But I have 10+ services defined in compose file. For last 1 year it was working file and after update and restarting docker service it suddenly giving me -

```
ERROR: for extremis_maxwell_1  Cannot start service maxwell: oci runtime error: container_linux.go:262: starting container process caused "process_linux.go:339: container init caused \"read init-p: connection reset by peer\""

ERROR: for maxwell  Cannot start service maxwell: oci runtime error: container_linux.go:262: starting container process caused "process_linux.go:339: container init caused \"read init-p: connection reset by peer\""
```

I tried re-installing everything but error remains the same.

Answer (score 2):

I was facing the same issue in case I use memory limit on CentOS 7.2. All you need to do is update your RedHat or CentOS kernel to `-514` patch or wait for `docker 17.06.1`.

`yum update kernel`

See https://github.com/moby/moby/issues/34046